# Code is unable to pick the macro declared

Tags: c++, c, macros

In the code below, the output values are not as defined in macro , is that because the values have to be available before pre processor stage?

```
#define INT_MAX 100

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = INT_MAX;
    x++;
    cout<<x<<INT_MAX;
}
```

Result is -2147483648

Comment: wait. who says it is undefined?

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: You are testing what happens when you increase past `INT_MAX`. It has nothing to do with it being a macro.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/EEVVA28931). What compiler are you using?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/ You are overwriting INT_MAX (Possibly on your compiler implementation this is getting included.)

Comment: I have added the answer too, the behaviour is undefined and the answer is junk value

Comment: Please check it and rate it  negative , don't be too fast in rating the question if possible try to provide a solution .

Comment: @user2256825 Choose a different name for your macro.

Comment: &Chris Thanks , problem was with the name

Comment: I have renamed the macro and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that after you are defining INT_MAX yourself, you are including iostream. That pulls in limits.h which redefines INT_MAX to be the maximum available 32-bit int - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits. Incrementing an int with the maximum value is undefined, but wraps around to the minimum possible int value on most CPU architecture/compiler combinations.

Depending on your compiler warning level, you should be getting a warning about INT_MAX being redefined. If you define it to 100 after the include statement, you should get 101.

Redefining macros provided by the standard library tends to lead to confusion, so I recommend you to pick a different name for your macro.

Comment: yes I tried defining it after include statement and its work fine now

Comment: definitely the original value would be overwritten . Is nt it? And this would also break the code if the same macro is used my other developers in this project and if they wouldn't know this definition

Comment: Yes. That's why I edited the answer to add "Redefining macros provided by the standard library tends to lead to confusion, so I recommend you to pick a different name for your macro."

Comment: "as expected" is not quite right, since overflowing a signed int is UB

Answer (score 9):

There is a macro named `INT_MAX` defined in `limits.h`. I assume that `iostream`includes `limits.h` and overwrites your own definition of `INT_MAX`.
This causes an integer overflow at `x++` because `INT_MAX` is the largest value that can be represented by an integer.